# Replace word every 7 times to the different words

Tags: notepad++

I have one word in the text that I want to replace every 7 times to the different words word1, word2, etc. Is it possible to do something with Notepad++ or should I create with a macro?

Example:

Word:  `word1, word2, word3...`

**Sample file:**

> For several REPLACE decades, cars were on the list  REPLACE of luxury products that only the rich could afford. However, REPLACE  with the passage of time, they became a REPLACE necessity for almost everyone. Today, there are REPLACE  numerous models of these vehicles that REPLACE  can satisfy the needs of every buyer out there. Of all the models REPLACE, BMW is one of the most classy, sophisticated, REPLACE and stylish choice.

**Expected result:**

> For several word1 decades, cars were on the list  word1 of luxury products that only the rich could afford. However, word1  with the passage of time, they became a word1 necessity for almost everyone. Today, there are word1numerous models of these vehicles that word1  can satisfy the needs of every buyer out there. Of all the models word1, BMW is one of the most classy, sophisticated, word2 and stylish choice.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but please, edit your question and add sample text and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a python script within the PythonScript plugin.

If it is not yet installed, follow this [guide](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above)

Create a script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> New Script)

Copy this code and save the file (for example `replace.py`):

```py
import re

counter = -1
# number of occurrences
nboccurr = 7
# define all the words you want, as many as you want
words = ['WORD1', 'WORD2', 'WORD3', 'WORD4', 'WORD5', 'WORD6']
word = ''
def replace(match):
    global counter, nboccurr, words, word
    counter += 1
    if counter % nboccurr == 0:
        word = str(words.pop(0))
    return word

editor.rereplace('REPLACE', replace)
```

- Open the file you want to change
- Run the script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> Scripts >> replace)
- Done

**Result for given example:**

[image]